# Data access to subordinates

Tags: data

I am stuck at the following question:-
Org wide default settings for accounts is private. A manager resides above the team in the role hierarchy. The manager wants to share some of the account details with the team.

Which feature can extend the viewing privileges to the team allowing them to see each others' data? Choose 2

A) Running user of a dashboard
B) Running user of a report
C) Dashboard folder access
D) Report folder access

The resource which I a following is saying that the answer should be A and B. 
But my opinion is that it should be A and C since in order to view the data the users need to view the dashboard and for that they should have access to the Dashboard  folder.
Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's something to ponder. I don't see *anyplace* in your question where it says *HOW* the manager plans to share the information with the subordinates. You seem to believe it's using a Dashboard, but I didn't get that from the question in the manner you quoted it to us. Hope that helps you.